# Show all elements on typeahead focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am looking for a smart head.

I am using Bootstrap's [typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) and currently when I click my textfield, nothing happens.

How can I make it so, that when my typeahead textfield is clicked or gets focused, it shows all the options in the typeahead? Because currently I have to start writing for it to show anything. Maybe use a scrollbar if there's a lot of items in my list.

Thank you kindly.

I use a `get` to get all my items, and then this is my code. I have more than one autocomplete on this page, so they all have different id's.

```
$.get('link', function (data) {
    var autocomplete = $('#typeahead-1').typeahead();
    autocomplete.data('typeahead').source = data;
    autocomplete.data('json', data);
}, 'json');
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
<input class="typeahead" type="text" >

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(".typeahead").on("click", function() {
      $(this).typeahead('open');
   });
}
</script>
```